# How to accept multiple argument types in a Matlab function validator?

Tags: matlab, function, validation

I have a certain function, say `myFunc`, that has an argument, say `funcHandleArg`, that should be a `function_handle` instance. However, this argument is not restricted to be one `function_handle`, but may in fact be a set of `function_handles`. Because Matlab does not accept non-scalar arrays of function handles `[func_handle1, func_handle2]`, I must pass this argument as a cell array of `function_handle`s `{func_handle1, func_handle2}`.

Now, my question is, how do I make sure that *both* `funcHandleArg = func_handle1` and `funcHandleArg = {func_handle1, func_handle2}` are *validated and accepted* as input arguments. Summarising, I'd like something like this:

```matlab
function output = myFunc(funcHandleArg, someOtherStuff)
arguments
    funcHandleArg function_handle "AND cells of function_handles"
    someOtherStuff otherStuff
end
output = someFunctionOf(funcHandleArg, someOtherStuff)
end
```

Comment: You can use `iscell` and `isa(funcHandleArg,'function_handle')` to determine what type of variable you have.

Comment: I see your point, defining some validator function I could validate whether my argument is either a `cell` or a `function_handle`. However, this does not solve my problem, because:
1) I don't check whether my argument is a cell *of `function_handle`s*
2) I don't have the easy-looking one-liner in the `arguments` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a simple validation function like this:

```
function myFunc(fcnOrFcns, otherArgs)
arguments
    fcnOrFcns {isOneOrMoreFunction}
    otherArgs
end
celldisp({fcnOrFcns, otherArgs});
end

function isOneOrMoreFunction(f)
isFcn = @(f) isa(f, 'function_handle');
assert(isFcn(f) || (iscell(f) && all(cellfun(isFcn, f))));
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that indeed answers my question. I was hoping for a somewhat simpler one-liner, but I guess Matlab syntax doesn't allow that.